# Any way to identify which rows were generated by which conditions in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have 2 tables, one containing the beginning and ending locations of a trip, and another containing the lat/lon positions of the vehicle every minute during that trip.  The tables are related by a tripID.

Something like this:

```
trip_table:
TRIPID | DEP | ARR
------------------
1      | CLE | CHI
2      | CLE | ATL
3      | ATL | CLE

position_table:
TRIPID | TIME              | LAT  | LON
-----------------------------------------
2      | May-20-2012T00:23 | 35.4 | -84.2
2      | May-20-2012T00:24 | 35.5 | -84.1
3      | May-21-2012T11:14 | 42.0 | -112.4
```

I have a query that is composed of 2 conditions:
1. Pull all position data where the trip departed/arrived at a specific location(s)
2. Pull all position data where the trip passed a specific lat/lon:

```
SELECT p.* FROM position AS p 
JOIN trip_table t ON (t.tripid = p.tripid)
WHERE (t.dep = 'CLE' OR t.arr = 'CLE)
OR (p.lat > 34 AND p.lat < 40 AND p.lon > -100 AND p.lon < -90)
```

My question is: is it possible to modify this query to determine which rows of the result came from the first condition (i.e. the trip departed/arrived at the specified location) and which came from the second (i.e. the trip passed a specified lat/lon)?

Currently my only thought is to run 2 separate queries but I'd like to avoid that if it's possible just to cut down on the overall number of queries.

If there's a standard SQL solution to this type of problem that would be great; if not then if there's a PostgreSQL-specific solution that would work too.

EDIT: In case anyone's wondering WHY I want to do this - the resulting positions are plotted on a map and I'd like to color code them based on whether they came from a bounded region or from between two arrival/departure locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT p.col1, p.col2, p.col3,
     t.dep = 'CLE' OR t.arr = 'CLE' AS first_condition,
     p.lat > 34 AND p.lat < 40 AND p.lon > -100 AND p.lon < -90 AS second_condition
FROM position AS p 
JOIN trip_table t ON (t.tripid = p.tripid)
WHERE (t.dep = 'CLE' OR t.arr = 'CLE')
OR (p.lat > 34 AND p.lat < 40 AND p.lon > -100 AND p.lon < -90)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can identify then via a case statement, as below. The code becomes a little redundant, but I've tested this on Oracle and it works:

```
SELECT p.*,
       case when t.dep = 'CLE' or t.arr = 'CLE' then 'FROM_CLE_CLAUSE'
            when (p.lat > 34 AND p.lat < 40 AND p.lon > -100 AND p.lon < -90) then 'OTHER_CLAUSE'
       end
  FROM position AS p 
  JOIN trip_table t 
    ON (t.tripid = p.tripid)
 WHERE (t.dep = 'CLE' OR t.arr = 'CLE)   
    OR (p.lat > 34 AND p.lat < 40 AND p.lon > -100 AND p.lon < -90)
```

Comment: Good solution thanks - voted up but I accepted the other answer just because it had a slightly simpler syntax.